# Semaphore.WaitOne/Release vs Monitor.Pulse/Wait

Tags: .net, multithreading

For me now it looks like functionally `Semaphore.WaitOne/Release` is equal to `Monitor.Wait/Pulse`. Skipping interprocess capabilities, speed (yes, Monitor is managed) other nonfunctional differences, what is real difference then?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The main purpose of a `Semaphore` is to control access to a finite set of resources. Thread can participate in resouce acquisition by calling `WaitOne` and `Release`. A thead should call `WaitOne` to acquire the resource.  However, it will only block if the semaphore's count reaches 0 otherwise the thread is free to acquire immediately. Once that thread is finished it should call `Release` to signal the semaphore that an extra slot has been freed up for another thread.

`Monitor.Wait` and `Monitor.Pulse` are drastically different. First and foremost there is no counting involved. If `Pulse` is called in the absence of any call to `Wait` then the signal is ignored and discarded. It is not queued up in the same way that a semaphore would. In fact, the behavior of `Wait` and `Pulse` has no inherent meaning at all. The `Wait` is simply waiting for a change in the state of the acquired lock (acquired from `Monitor.Enter`). The `Pulse` is the signal that something changed. That is why you often see `Wait` called in a `while` loop. The waiting thread must retest the wait condition because it has no idea what changed!

`Monitor.Wait` and `Monitor.Pulse` are fundamental synchronization mechanisms that can be used to form pretty much any other synchronization device including semaphores.

Comment: It's often best to regard `Pulse` as a signal that something "may have" changed.  The essential idea is that if a method needs to wait for a resource to change in some fashion (e.g. a queue to have data in it), and that change can only be made by code which holds the lock on that resource, the former method can test whether the change has happened and, if not, call `Monitor.Wait` on the lock.  If every method which changes the locked resources calls `PulseAll`, anyone that's waiting for a change will be woken up and given a chance to see whether the change they were waiting for has happened.

Answer (score 2):

Monitor.Wait/Pulse provides you with a condition variable, which is more like an auto-reset event than a semaphore (but not exactly). The main difference is that a semaphore has a count, which means you don't need to lock anything in order to ensure you don't miss a pulse (unlike with Monitor.Wait).